# How can I track every SELECT operation that is done on database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to track every operation that is done on my database. In order to do that, using a trigger after every delete,insert,update I log data such as EventValue,EventDate,ChangedBy in a log database. I do this because I want to write some automated tests. System is not completely testable , so after thinking about many solutions I ended up doing this. Sometimes I have to log SELECT and this can not be done by triggers. Also I checked event notification and this was not suitable for me too. This is the SQL code for my trigger:

```
USE [N_IAG_DB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[ContentTrigger]    Script Date: 8/20/2022 10:17:32 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ContentTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Content_1371]
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   PRINT('Executed an operation on database.')
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   
   INSERT INTO TableLog
   (
      EventVal,
      EventDate,
      ChangedBy
    )
       VALUES (
          EVENTDATA(),
          GETDATE(),
          USER
       );
END
```

This would be very very helpful if you can tell me how can I track selects.

Comment: Are you really using sql server 2008? You need to upgrade to a more recent version. If you do, you can use extended events to track selects

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/distributed-replay/sql-server-distributed-replay?view=sql-server-ver16 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/replay-a-trace-file-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: No the tag is wrong. i use sql server management studio 2019

Comment: @ParmidaGranfar, SSMS is only a client tool. Edit your tag to specify the SQL Server database version are you using. EVENTDATA() serves no purpose in your DML trigger since it is only valid in a DDL or login trigger. Take a look at extended events to capture what you need with a server trace.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [SQL Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) for all of this (including your inserts, updates, and deletes). It has several advantages specific to your situation:

1. You can specify it at a schema or database level. If you're trying to capture all CRUD traffic with triggers, you'd have to write one for every table, view, etc in your database. And, as you've discovered, there's no such thing as a select trigger.
2. You get details (i.e. who, what, when) for the operation by default.
3. It logs to a file (or the event log, but that's really more for security-type audits). So you can run your workload, stop the audit, and copy or move those files elsewhere for analysis.
4. You don't have to modify your database schema to enable it.

---

All that said, I will caution you that this should only be enabled for brief periods and really consider whether or not you need to do this in a production environment. Even in a moderately busy system, what you're wanting to do (regardless of the means by which you achieve it) is going to produce a *lot* of data and have an impact on system performance.